# Sort by name with jquery from data coming from MongoDB

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb

So I'm trying to build a basic todo list app. I've got most stuff working but I can't seem to figure out how to sort my list of todos.

I want to sort it in the dom only, not on the mongodb. I want to click a button and then sort the list (addding listener via jquery).

I have this snippet of code that goes through my db and loads the todos on the page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("/api/todos")
    .then(addAllTodos)

    //insert todos from db to page
    function addAllTodos(todos){
        todos.forEach((todo) => {
            //duplicated code made into function
            addSingleTodo(todo);
            //_.sortBy(todo, ['name', 1]);
        });
    };
```

I have tried to sort it from here with sort() with no succes. I tried using lodash but I beleive that only works for node. Setting a listener for a button and creating another function isn't working either, mainly because i think that manipulates just a single todo, and not the whole list.

I was thinking about getting the data from my addAllTodos and sorting that, but I'm stuck. The getjson is supposed to return an array, and I beleive what i want to do is order said array, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also here is the addSinlgeTodo function

```
function addSingleTodo(todoData){
    //create our new todo
    let newTodo = $("<li><span><i class='far fa-trash-alt'></i></span>" + todoData.name + "</li>");
    //store todo id
    newTodo.data("id", todoData._id);
    //add completed boolean
    newTodo.data("completed", todoData.completed);
    //add completed class to todo
    if(todoData.completed){
        newTodo.addClass("completed");
    }
    //append new todo
    $("ul").append(newTodo);
};
```

Comment: please share json from mongodb and expected output

Comment: Can you validate that `/api/todos` does infact return an array.  And what the structure of that array is.  That is the thing you want to sort right?

Comment: `0 
completed false
_id "5c75c4ecf04a0308208c24ac"
name "Test1"
__v 0
1 
completed false
_id "5c75c4f1f04a0308208c24ad"
name "123456"
__v 0
2 
completed false
_id "5c75c4f5f04a0308208c24ae"
name "This is a todo"
__v 0`  
  
Gonna have to edit this formatting, but this is what the json returns now, as I understood it, this type of data from mongodb or maybe from the getjson was laid out as an array
Edit, i suck at formatting, im sorry

Comment: If you provide resultant (after the jsonget) HTML and the button that will control it an answer will be more forthcoming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `/api/todos` returns an array, here is an example;

> The sort function can use a custom compare function that can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description), basically return -1 if less than, +1 if greater, and 0 if equal.  The default `sort()` only works on strings.

```js
var lst = [{
    name: "adam",
    id: 1
  },
  {
    name: "neocero",
    id: 2
  },
  {
    name: "charlie",
    id: 3
  }
];
console.log(lst); //unsorted
addAllTodos(lst);

function addAllTodos(todos) {
  todos.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
    else if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
    else return 0;
  });
  console.log(todos); //sorted
  //do your magic, now it is sorted.
  //        todos.forEach((todo) => {
  //            //duplicated code made into function
  //            addSingleTodo(todo);
  //        });
};
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. This seems to work. However I think Im missing something conceptually... Do i have to go fetch my db everytime i want to order my list? Say order from az and then za?

Comment: Why don't you just create another function which would sort it from z to a ?

Comment: I have tried that, but I cant call a function inside an event listener apperantly, so I am now stuck again lol

Comment: With some re-factoring of the code and an understanding of what you are trying to accomplish there should be no issues sorting in either direction, or by whichever criteria you like whenever you want to.  More explanation would be required (HTML/structure/goals).  I would suggest you ask a new question with a functional `stack-snippet`